# Como fazer o botão toggle exibir apenas o conteúdo desejado numa tabela gerada por ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, react, next.js, toggle

Estou criando uma aplicação em Next.js e acabou que aconteceu um comportamento que eu não esperava.

Após ler um **json,** monto uma tabela com as informações neste json! E para cada linha de informação existem mais informações ocultas no qual eu preciso ocultar e exibir apenas se o usuário clicar nos botões de exibição **- Botão Detalhe e Botão Pedido**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na imagem acima eu cliquei em detalhes do primeiro item da tabela, e gostaria que ele exibisse detalhes apenas do primeiro item mesmo! Mas ele começa a exibir detalhes de todos os outros itens da tabela.

A parte do código que gera isso está mais ou menos assim:

```
//Controle de visualização de exibir informação
const [isVisible2, setIsVisible2] = useState(false);
const toggleVisibility2 = () =>{
        setIsVisible2(!isVisible2);
    }

const [isVisible1, setIsVisible1] = useState(false);
const toggleVisibility1 = () =>{
        setIsVisible1(!isVisible1);
    }
```

...

```
//Botão para exibir informação
<button className="h-10 px-4 ..." onClick={toggleVisibility1}>
```

...

```
//Verificação para exibir ou não a tabela
{isVisible1 &&
   <table>
       <thead className="bg-slate-300">
             <th className="p-3 text-sm ...">id</th>
              <th className="p-3 text-sm ...">Data</th>
```

Eles estão dentro de um map! É um map dentro de outro map, haja visto que no array de objetos tem objeto dentro de outro objeto!

```
//Tabela principal
{announcements.map(announcement => (
    <td>{announcement.ads_id}</td>
    
//Tabela dentro da tabela, onde a informação precisa ficar ocultada até
//O usuário clicar no botão
    announcement.order_details.map(detail =>(
        <td>{detail.name}</td>
    ))
)}
```

É possível ver a aplicação rodando aqui: [Deploy](https://next-test-rn8i.vercel.app/)

E o código completo está aqui: [Github](https://github.com/moraesWesley/next-test/tree/main)

O arquivo que acontece tudo isso é no: **next-test/app/components
/Announcements.jsx**

Portanto, a pergunta final é: Como faço para exibir apenas os detalhes do botão clicado, sem ativar a visibilidade de todos os outros?